# How to check Windows XP Stack canaries status?

Tags: windows-xp, buffer-overflow, exploit, dep

How can I check the status of stack canaries status in Windows XP? I only found that we can able to check DEP status and can turn/off. How to achieve that for stack canaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike DEP, canaries are added at compile time using compiler options like [-fstack-protector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for GCC, and [/GS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx) for Microsoft Visual C++. They are not system wide, so you cannot check the status "in Windows XP".